# Hide/show jquery only works on 1 div

Tags: javascript, wordpress, hide, show

I am creating a page that has 4 different sections. In each section there are 2 buttons that hide/show 2 different divs. Right now it only works on the top div and when you click the buttons in the other 3 divs, they open the top div. The content is being pulled from wordpress posts. Here is the javascript I am using.

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.expander').on('click', function() {
    if ($('#TableData').is(":visible")) {
      $('#TableData').hide();
    } else {
      $('#TableData').show();
    }
    $('#TableData2').hide();
    return false;
      });

      $('.expander2').on('click', function() {
    if ($('#TableData2').is(":visible")) {
      $('#TableData2').hide();
    } else {
      $('#TableData2').show();
    }
    $('#TableData').hide();
    return false;
      });
    });
```

Here is the html:

```
                <div class="popup-open">
                    <div class="icons-large"></div>
                    <div class="icons-large"></div>
                    <div class="title">Title</div>
            <a href="#" rel="bookmark" title="" class="expander show_hide">WHAT'S IN THE BAG</a></br>
            <a href="" rel="bookmark" title="" class="expander2 show_hide2">PLAYER HISTORY</a>


                    </div>
                    </div>  


            <div id="TableData">
            <div class="slidingDiv">
                  <div id="tabs-1">
                                    <div class="witb-tab">


                                            <div class="row">
                                                <a target="_blank" href="#">
                                                    <div class="image">
                                                        <img src="#" alt="">
                                                        <a target="_blank" class="product-name" href="" title=">">

                                                </a>
                                                    </div>
                                                </a>
                                            </div>



                                    </div>
                                    <a href="#" class="expander show_hide" style="float:right;">CLOSE</a>
                            </div>


                  </div>
            </div>
                <div id="TableData2">
                <div class="slidingDiv2">
                   <div class="column left">

                            <!-- post thumbnail -->

                            <!-- /post thumbnail -->

                            <div class="player-biography">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="column right">
                  <div id="tabs-2">
                                    <div class="content-wrap"></div>
                                </div>
                             <a href="#" class="expander2 show_hide2" style="float:right;">CLOSE</a>    
                  </div>
                  </div>
                  </div>
```

Comment: Are you duplicating any of your IDs? Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: Create snippet code with html, js and css

Comment: Not getting any errors. Here is the html how it is being displayed.

Comment: I updated my code with the html that I am using.

Comment: since you're using jquery ($), take a look at with .toggleClass()

Comment: Post the rendered HTML. The PHP is irrelevant to your question.

Comment: I stripped the php out of the code